# Android global events

Tags: android, global, event-listener

I am developing a background application for Android 2.1 and I would like to register listener to handle global events like screen shuts down / screen comes alive / unlocked and stuff like that.

I also would like to know if it's possible to register events like onLowBattery (for example to shutdown my application) or when connected to the internet.

Comment: this lead me here https://www.google.co.in/?client=ubuntu#channel=fs&q=android+event+worldwide&gfe_rd=cr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) documentation. It gives all possible intents for which you can register. For example if you want to register for low batter you should use [ACTION_BATTERY_LOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW) action.